# Extract polygon data for each neighbourhood from shapefile

Tags: shapefile, web-mapping

I have a dataset that has four types of files with the following file extensions - .DBF, .PRJ, .SHP, .SHX

My goal is to get all the polygon coordinates for each neighbourhood and draw the boundary outline on the Google map when a user is on a specific neighbourhood page. Currently the data source for the site is a MySQL database.

I have tried converting the shapefile to GeoJSON but then parsing that file is time taking.

I have also tried using tools such as QGIS and shp2sql etc.

I would like to know what is the best way to get the main attributes from the dataset along with each neighbourhood's polygon coordinates?

Comment: Did you try to convert the Shapefile to KML? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387042/best-way-to-overlay-an-esri-shapefile-on-google-maps

Comment: <Polygon><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-80.21463341110001,25.782154451300002 -80.21588353300001,25.782696872700001 -80.217973576800006,25.7833078056 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>

Are the coordinates in [Longituge,Latitude] order?

Comment: That isn't a valid KML. The coordinates are long,lat if that point falls in Miami, Florida.